# How to make a variable play in a yes or no question in python ( this is my 2 day of coding python so pardon me if I am asking a dumb question

Tags: python

I am making a python program where a person asks for your name then askis if you want to play a game this is where I am having trouble because I made a yes or no problem in python but then I set all the code for the game as a variable called "game" game = game code  and then if someone says  yes to playing the game then it says a message saying sure lets play a game then I put the variable "game" like so  meaing it says a message and starts playing the game with the user

if user_input.lower() == 'yes': print('ok Sure let us play a  game called "Number guessing Game 1-10' + game )

I will upload the .py file in this question

```
print('Hi I am Mike A python frame work')
 game = import random

num = random.randint(1, 10)
guess = None

while guess != num:
    guess = input("guess a number between 1 and 10: ")
    guess = int(guess)

    if guess == num:
        print("congratulations! you won!")
        break
    else:
        print("nope, sorry. try again!")




NAME = input("What is your Name?:")
print("Hi," + NAME   )
user_input = input('Do you want to play a game (yes/no): ( I know you will try all the options :)')

if user_input.lower() == 'yes':
    print('ok Sure let us play a  game called "Number guessing Game 1-10' + game )

elif user_input.lower() == "no":
    print('Ok Bye! If you want to play a game come back to this .py file ')
```

I was expecting a message saying welcome to the game number guessing then the variable "game" plays I first tryed to make the game a variable and that is now what I am stuck on

Comment: This is a syntax error:  `game = import random`.  Change it to `import random`.

Answer (score 0):

Er, make the variable **game** as a func.

```
import random
print('Hi I am Mike A python frame work')


def game():
    num = random.randint(1, 10)
    guess = None

    while guess != num:
        guess = input("guess a number between 1 and 10: ")
        guess = int(guess)

        if guess == num:
            print("congratulations! you won!")
            break
        else:
            print("nope, sorry. try again!")
    return ''


NAME = input("What is your Name?:")
print("Hi," + NAME   )
user_input = input('Do you want to play a game (yes/no): ( I know you will try all the options :)')

if user_input.lower() == 'yes':
    print('ok Sure let us play a  game called "Number guessing Game 1-10')
    game()

elif user_input.lower() == "no":
    print('Ok Bye! If you want to play a game come back to this .py file ')
```

Comment: Thank you Kaison L for helping me learn about functions and with my game

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

A variable is basically used for storing values. If you want to group codes to be used in other places, you need to put the game code into a [function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp) named `game` and call it when the user input is 'yes'.